# IOS safari position fixed issue when keyboard active

Tags: ios, iphone, reactjs, safari

I am trying to use position fixed to work well on iOS devices.

This is how it looks when the keyboard has not opened:
https://ibb.co/jq5g4J

For the above chat window I have used this piece of code:

```
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
```

When I tap the input box (to write a message), keyboard opens up and the top part becomes hidden and it looks like this:

https://ibb.co/gVQ3Jd

I think ios is ignoring `top: 0` when the keyboard opens up. What can I do to avoid that?

Comment: _Try opening this page:- production site on ios safari and try to play with the messenger a bit_ - how about you just provide the clear bug description, perhaps a screen recording and some code instead. **You** have the problem that needs fixing, it's in **your** interest to provide all the information necessary.

Comment: @mag_zbc I could but the code is huge and I cannot figure out where the problem is exactly

Comment: @mag_zbc I am trying to upload a video link if that might help.

Comment: https://vimeo.com/user87393473/review/280334933/f56af4c1d8 here is the link to the video

Comment: Actually, I am working on React application that would be rendered inside an Iframe and I want the chat window to take the whole screen when it is active so I used a "position: fixed property" on the div rendering the chat. I have not experienced this problem on devices using chrome or android devices. In ios safari the position fixed element becomes scrollable and is no longer in the viewport